# Single page app user session

Tags: reactjs, session, redux

I have SPA using React and Redux.
After the user logs in, I save his data in redux state.

In some cases, the user information can be changed (such as being attached to some roles). How can I update the user data (without using websockets)? 
Do I have to return the user on each request to the client? Or do I have to update his JWT token on each request?

Thanks.

Comment: If the `role` is updated on the server, you have no way to communicate that to the browser unless you use websocket or do pulling continuously. Changing JWT on each request is not intuitive but you can send a request to get user's information periodically and update your store. 

This is called `pulling`. You can do it when the pages are transitioning or a component is updating or in an arbitrary intervals.